# Convert Byte Array to Bit Array?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

How would I go about converting a bytearray to a bit array?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The obvious way; using the constructor that takes a byte array:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(arrayOfBytes);
```

Comment: What about to a pre-existing bit array?

Answer (score 16):

It depends on what you mean by "bit array"... If you mean an instance of the `BitArray` class, Guffa's answer should work fine.

If you actually want an array of bits, in the form of a `bool[]` for instance, you could do something like that :

```
byte[] bytes = ...
bool[] bits = bytes.SelectMany(GetBits).ToArray();

...

IEnumerable<bool> GetBits(byte b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        yield return (b & 0x80) != 0;
        b *= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is more appropriate than the answer above cos result contains leading zeros. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitArray bits)
 {
    int numBytes = bits.Count / 8;
    if (bits.Count % 8 != 0) numBytes++;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];
    int byteIndex = 0, bitIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Count; i++) {
        if (bits[i])
            bytes[byteIndex] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - bitIndex));
        bitIndex++;
        if (bitIndex == 8) {
            bitIndex = 0;
            byteIndex++;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Just curious.. Doesn't he want the function the other way?!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitArray` to create a stream of bits from a `byte` array. Here an example:

```
string testMessage = "This is a test message";

byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testMessage);

BitArray messageBits = new BitArray(messageBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte number  = 128;
Convert.ToString(number, 2);
```

=> out: 10000000

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detail of what you are doing and how it is working?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-7.0) >ToString(Byte, Int32) 
Converts the value of an 8-bit unsigned integer to its equivalent string representation in a specified base.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(bool[] byteArray)
{
    return = byteArray
               .Select(
                    (val1, idx1) => new { Index = idx1 / 8, Val = (byte)(val1 ? Math.Pow(2, idx1 % 8) : 0) }
                )
                .GroupBy(gb => gb.Index)
                .Select(val2 => (byte)val2.Sum(s => (byte)s.Val))
                .ToArray();
}
```