# Converting C# byte to BitArray

Tags: c#, byte, bitarray

Is there any predefined function available to convert a `byte` into `BitArray`?

One way would be to inspect every bit of the `byte` value and then perform **bitwise** operation. I was wondering if there is any way which is more straightforward than this.

Comment: You should rephrase your question. Do you want to convert byte or byte array to System.Collections.BitArray?

Comment: my exact situation is to convert 3 bytes from a byte Array. The method described below would work for me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, using the appropriate [`BitArray()` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.100).aspx) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548018/convert-byte-array-to-bit-array):

```
var bits = new BitArray(arrayOfBytes);
```

You can call it with `new BitArray(new byte[] { yourBite })` to create an array of one byte.

Comment: how about three bytes at a time, say something like: new BitArray(new byte[] { myBite1, myBite2, myBite2 })

Answer (score 8):

if you have a byte number or even an integer, etc.

```
BitArray myBA = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(myNumber).ToArray());
```

Note: you need a reference to System.Linq

Answer (score 3):

Solution is simple, just two instructions (which are marked in following code), simply convert byte to binary using `Convert.ToString(btindx,2)`, zero pad  the resultant string to 8 bits (or lengths 8),`strBin.PadLeft(8,'0');` and concatenate all binary strings to form a bit stream of your byte array, If you like, you can also form an array of strings to separate each byte's binary representation.

```
    byte[] bt = new byte[2] {1,2};

    string strBin =string.Empty;
    byte btindx = 0;
    string strAllbin = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
    {
        btindx = bt[i];

        strBin = Convert.ToString(btindx,2); // Convert from Byte to Bin
        strBin = strBin.PadLeft(8,'0');  // Zero Pad

        strAllbin += strBin;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the `BitArray` in question is not intended to be a multiple of the number of bits in a byte `(8)` you can do something like this to ensure the correct number of bits when converting from `byte[]` to `BitArray`:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray (this BitArray bits) {
    byte[] ret = new byte[(bits.Length - 1) / 8 + 1];
    bits.CopyTo (ret, 0);
    return ret;
}

public static BitArray ToBitArray (this byte[] bytes, int bitCount) {
    BitArray ba = new BitArray (bitCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; ++i) {
        ba.Set (i, ((bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 0x01) > 0);
    }
    return ba;
}
```