# How to get a bit value of byte

Tags: c#, data-conversion

When I tried to convert byte to bits using `var bits = Convert.ToString(tmp, 2);`
`tmp` is a byte values 33 for example. Now the `bits` is string '100001', how should I get every single bit value of `bits`? For example `if(bits[0] == 1) ...do something`

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204666/converting-c-sharp-byte-to-bitarray

Comment: If `bits` is a `string`, you probably want to compare to a `char` value: `if (bits[0] == '1')`. However, you don't even need to do this, as you can simply access bits in the initial integer variable: `if ((tmp & 0x0001) != 0)`, similar to what you would do in C, Java or other C-like languages.

Comment: @Groo Thanks, It's the same as C and it works fine!